# cakephp variable available in index/view, but not in controller

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have 2 Models/Views/Controllers - Users and Jobs

Through the Auth method, I have the following being set from within the AppController:

```
$this->set('current_user', $this->Auth->user());
```

So, once a user has logged into the system, I can use the user data.

I have id, name, email, username etc in the users table, and I have a field called "group_id".  I also have a "group_id" field in the jobs table, and what I want to do is only show records/allow access to records where the group_id from the job record matches the group_id of the user.

So, I can use the following in the jobs index view:

```
echo var_dump($current_user);
```

Which will print something like this:

```
array(11) { ["id"]=> string(2) "13" ["firstname"]=> string(2) "My" ["surname"]=> string(4) "Name" ["email"]=> string(25) "myname@anemailaddress.com" ["username"]=> string(6) "myname" ["muso_email_notify"]=> string(1) "0" ["group_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["active"]=> string(1) "0" ["activationID"]=> string(0) "" ["memberaccesslevel"]=> string(1) "0" ["role"]=> string(7) "regular" }
```

So, now when I am selecting all jobs within my JobsController, I want to use something like this (it might not be quite correct):

```
$this->set('jobs', $this->Job->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Job.group_id' => $current_user['group_id']))));
```

However, when I go to the index view of Jobs, I get the undefined variable error:

Notice (8): Undefined variable: current_user [APP/Controller/JobsController.php, line 9]

I can't work out what I'm doing wrong?  The variable works in the view, but not in the controller logic.

I'm using cake 2.3.4 with mysql database

Comment: The `set` method makes the variable available to the views; It does not create a variable in the global scope. You will need to use a session variable or something along those lines if you want the information available globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$this->set() just sets the variable to the view, so it's logical to get that error on the controller. In the controller you'll have to use

```
public function someFunction() {
    $current_user = $this->Auth->user();
    echo $current_user['group_id'];
}
```

If you want to avoid doing that on every function and have a current user variable *everywhere*, do something like this in the AppController

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    //create new variable
    public $_current_user = array();

    public function beforeFilter() {
         $this->_current_user = $this->Auth->user();
         $this->set('current_user', $this->_current_user);
    }
}
```

and you'll have the current user available in the controller with `$this->_current_user` and in the view with `$current_user`

Either way, it's going to be available for you, it just depends on how you want to access the variable. Regardless, keep in mind that `$this->set()` is just for setting variables to the views.

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much.  I will give that a go, and remember about $this->set().

Answer (score 0):

For variables *in general*, Nunser provided some useful information. However, to obtain information of the *currently logged-in user*, the AuthComponent also has a 'static' interface that allows you to access information of the user anywhere in your application.

### Advantages of the AuthComponent (static) interface

Using the static interface makes it easier to access that information and also leaves your code a lot cleaner, because you don't have to set 'viewVars' to pass that information to your views/elements, **which reduces code duplucation** if you need to use that information in different views/actions of multiple controllers.

For example, to get the `group_id` of the current user inside a view, just do:

```
echo AuthComponent::user('group_id');
```

As described earlier, this works *anywhere* inside your app, so, for example, can also be used inside a Helper (or even inside a Model, but this may not be proper MVC)

For more information, read this part of the manual: [Accessing the logged-in User](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user)